# Taking any integer value from JSON into IOS Application

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode5, zbar-sdk

I seem to be having trouble with loading the `id` value which is displayed within my iphone application.

When I run the app, it loads the the name, price and a and an image URL. The only section which fails to load depending on its value is the `id`. Is anyone able to tell me why this happens just by looking at this code?

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/AM.php?id=%@",self.scannedValue]
```

When I change %@ to an integer value it shows the image and other info for that `id` number, but I'm trying to get that part of the code to take ANY `id` number.

```
localhost/AM.php?id=101 

localhost/AM.php?id=102  

localhost/AM.php?id=103 <<---- All of the ID's display data about a different item etc..
```

I set self scannedValue in my `scannedViewController.m`, I am basically using the `zBar Scanner` to scan a barcode and display the fields I mentioned above.

Can someone please tell me why i have trouble with the code displaying different id's? I already tried the format specifier %@ but it fails to work.

Code from my `viewcontroller.m`

```
- (void) readerView:(ZBarReaderView *)readerView didReadSymbols:(ZBarSymbolSet *)symbols    fromImage:(UIImage *)image {
for (ZBarSymbol *sym in symbols) {
    [reader stop];
    [reader removeFromSuperview];
    scannedValue = sym.data;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetails" sender:self];
    break;
}
```

}

In this

```
scannedValue = sym.data;
```

is string, `sum` is `ZBarSymbol` class object

In the `ZBarSymbol` class

```
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString *data;
```

is the starting value.

When successfully scanned a value it will return a `NSString *data` in delegate method.

Comment: Is self.scannedValue a string or an integer?

Comment: Add more code where you are having the problem dealing with the id. `self.scannedValue`, what type is it and what is the `NSLog`ed value? Show the declaration and setting code.

Comment: @kentoh are you able to see the edit?

Comment: @Zaph are you able to see the edit?

Comment: @user3310055 if you nslog scannedValue, what so u get?

Comment: It displays the id number of the code which is scanned, but fails to go to the next view. It just stalls and goes into an error.

Comment: You have `scannedValue = sym.data` but `scannedValue`  is not declared in the method. perhaps that should be: `self. scannedValue`.

Comment: Fix any compiler warnings. Run the Xcode Analyzer and fix any warnings/errors.

Comment: user3310055 asked you to `NSLog` the `scannedValue` but you did not provide the result. If you want help provide more complete answers and more complete example code. Some of the code posted would not even compile.